# Safely inserting data into a database in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, security, serialization

Do I need to take some extra measures (encode or smth. else) to make data pass to and out of SQL Server safely?

What I mean is I have an xml column in a SQL Server table that stores any serialized text data that potentially could be malicious. So do I need to do encoding, put text into CDATA tag or smth else? Or do SQL Server and .NET serializers takes all the actions for me?

I've tried to pass some malicious data such as `value='<b><i>Hi, I said 'this won't work'... I'm p&k</i></b>` and similar and everything seems to work.

Do I need to be concerned about it or should I leave everything as it is?

Comment: Show us some code you use to store the data now, and you will get answers if that's safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are constructing the SQL INSERT statement by concatenating the values together with the SQL, then you are doing it wrong.

If your SQL has placeholders for the values, and your database interface library allows you to supply the parameters, and your library constructs and performs the insert, then you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "can I insert something into a SQL Server XML column that *will break SQL Server*", then the answers should either be "Probably not" or "Yes, but I am going to responsibly tell Microsoft about it and wait for a fix, rather than posting it on SO"

If, on the other hand, the question is "Can I insert something into a SQL Server XML column that *will break my application, or another application that uses the data*", then it depends upon what those applications are.  XML by itself is harmless, but your software or other software using that data (web browsers, etc) may have vulnerabilities that you need to account for.